# How to make "one" css3 shadow for menu and content?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to apply "one" shadow for menu and page itself?

Here is what I mean:

[image]

[Code on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfXX8/)

Comment: If you mean to make box-shadow surround both content parts as one, then no that won't work out smoothly

Comment: @ArgsKwargs ok... and what about inset shadows? any alternatives?

Comment: I'd be a bit more economical on the CSS shadows, my Chrome is having a tough time rendering them...

Comment: @ptriek currently, I'm just toying around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well usually I'd say do as much without images as possible.. But honestly I think a background image is a better alternative in this case, you only need one on top (1000px x 200px) one for the body (1000px x 1px) and one at the bottom.. However to make it dynamically adaptive for extra or less tabs you will need more complicated slices and/or javascript.. :-)